# VBA - Referencing a jagged array index in For loop

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, jagged-arrays

I have an array of arrays and am trying to cycle through it and run macros based on the index in the array. My code is as follows:

```
Sub vbaReportGenerator()


    Dim reportList As Variant


    'sheet, button, report
    reportList = Array( _
        Array("scpSumBox", "RPscopeOfWorkSummary", "Scope of Work Summary"), _
        Array("prpSumBox", "RPprpFixtures", "Proposed Fixture Summary"), _
        Array("exstSumBox", "RPexistingFixtures", "Existing Fixture Summary") _
        )

    'Cycle through list and create reports
    For i = 0 To UBound(reportList)
        If Sheets("REPORT").reportList(i)(0).Value = True Then
            Dim report As String
            report = reportList(i)(1)
            call report
        End If
    Next i
```

The debugger is highlighting "call report" and stating that it expects a sub.
I tried changing call report to a message box so I can see how it pulls the report name, but then highlights the first line of for loop and states object does not support property or method.  So it appears that I have two issues here

The items in the array are as follows
Index 0 - name of a radio button
index 1 - name of a macro that creates a report
index 2 - name of the report that it will eventually create

Right now I am trying to get the For Loop to run the macro at the index in reportList

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Is the radiobutton a Forms control or ActiveX?

Comment: ActiveX.  Scott Craner's suggested thread solved the issue of referencing the macro.  Although I am still getting "object doesn't support this property or method" on If Sheets("REPORT").reportList(i)(0).Value = True Then

Comment: Worksheets don't have a `reportList` property, so that's why you get the error.  If you want to access a control on a worksheet by its name, you need something like `Sheets("REPORT").OLEObjects(reportList(i)(0)).Object.Value`